# Git not picking up the correct key according to .ssh/config

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have Git on Windows and have two ssh keys for two different git repos that I want to connect to.

I created .ssh under `C:\Users\MyUser` and in that dir I created the config file.

My config file looks like this

```
Host workgit
    HostName    git.company.com
    IdentityFile C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh\id_rsa
    User    mycorpusername

Host github
    HostName    github.com
    IdentityFile C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh\personal_id
    User    mygithubuser
```

When I try to clone from my work repo it works fine. For some reason though when I try my presonal github it doesn't read personal_id instead it tries to read id_Rsa and iterations of it.

ssh -vT git@github.com

```
C:\Program Files\Git>ssh -vT hit@github.com
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'hit'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:         <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa     SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I tried setting a HOME env var but that didn't do anything.

I am using git-cmd.exe

Comment: As Jakuje said, the line should read `Host gitub.com` (and then you don't need the `HostName line`). You probably also want `IdentitiesOnly yes`. In any case, this is an ssh issue (and possibly a Windows-ssh issue) and has nothing to do with Git itself: Git just invokes ssh.

Answer (score 2):

The line in `ssh_config` should be

```
Host github.com
```

or you should use only

```
ssh -vT git@github
```

As a result, the `ssh` should use appropriate key.